# Get total size of combined uploaded files with JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page where a user can upload a document. There is also a button to add more documents (as seen per image).

[image: Dynamicaly added upload points]

[image: after adding upload button]

I want to check as each file that has been added or removed from the upload section to make sure that the size does not exceed 10 MB.

So if a user uploads 3 separate files of 2 MB and then adds a file which is 5 MB, the submit button will disable until one of the files are removed because it has gone over the 10 MB limit.

The rows can be added dynamically, so I was doing it by class and trying to sum the running total.

Here is what I have so far, available at [JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9bhcB/1210/)

```
<form class="upload-form">
  <input class='upload-file' type="file" id="upload0">
  <input class='upload-file' type="file" id="upload1">
  <input class='upload-file' type="file" id="upload2">
  <input class='upload-file' type="file" id="upload3">
  <input id='submitBtn' type=submit>
</form>
```

The issue is, that if I add a file and then remove it, it does not reflect the current running total.

```
$("document").ready(function() {

  var fileArr = [];

  $(".upload-file").on('change',function() {
    var fileInput = $('.upload-file');

    var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size;
    fileArr.push(fileSize);

    var totalSize = 0;

    for (var i in fileArr) {
      alert(fileArr[i]);
      totalSize = totalSize + fileArr[i];             
    }

    if (totalSize > 10485759) {
      alert('Over Max Size');
      $(submitBtn).prop("disabled",true);
    }

  });
});
```

I tried this way also, but could not reset when a file was removed.[JFIDDLE-2](http://jsfiddle.net/9bhcB/1211/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The logic in your code can be simplified by just incrementing a single counter within the `each()` loop. You can then check the total once the loop has completed to see if the combined file size is valid. Try this:

```
$(".upload-file").on('change', function() {
  var totalSize = 0;

  $(".upload-file").each(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
      totalSize += this.files[i].size;
    }
  });

  var valid = totalSize <= 10485759;
  if (!valid) 
    alert('Over Max Size');

  $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled", !valid);
});
```

Note that this method will also work with `multiple` file inputs, as the jsFiddle below shows:

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9bhcB/1220/)

Comment: This worked, thank you. Although I needed to change the first line to 
 $(document.body).on('change', '.upload-file', function () { to pick up the dynamically created inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle of it working http://jsfiddle.net/9bhcB/1214/

Change your javascript to be:

```
$("document").ready(function(){ 
    $(".upload-file").on('change',function() {
       var fileArr = [];
        $.each($(".upload-file"), function(index, value) {
         input = value;
         file = input.files[0];
         fileArr.push(file.size);
          var totalSize = 0;

               for (var i in fileArr) {

                  totalSize = totalSize + fileArr[i];             
                                }

                if (totalSize > 10485759) {
                    alert('Over Max Size');
                  $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled",true);
                }
                else {
                  $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled",false);
                }

      });



    });

    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works very well, however, if the user enters 3 files which violate the max size limit, they will be hit with the same alert box 3 times in a row.  Is there a way to break out of that loop as soon as the max size is violated?

Comment: If you want to break out of a loop just type break;

Comment: I tried it with a break and it doesn't want to work now. http://jsfiddle.net/9bhcB/1219/

Comment: I threw an `alert(totalSize);` after your for loop and totalSize doesn't change after the first file. You are only pushing file 0 every time.

Comment: place a varible before $.each(... , and set it to true/false here: if (totalSize > 10485759), the check it after the $.each()

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things looking at your fiddle -

1. fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; is returning a greater than 0 value only if the file is added
2. Since when an upload element is "removed" as in de-selected, all you get is a empty array of files..so, you would need to track the id of the files and their sizes and calculate the combined sizes of all files based on that...

Here is how you get the ID of the element "changed" -

```
var elmId = $( this ).attr('id');
```

and you use this to track the file sizes.

I forked your fiddle to make this work. Here you go -
http://jsfiddle.net/9bhcB/1226/

Also, there is a lot of quick and dirty JS in there that you may need to clean up, but it does what you are looking for!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to your code would be one input that allows for multiple files to be uploaded at once. The collection of files can then be `slice`-d up and totaled with a smaller function:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#file').on('change', function() {
    var total = [].slice.call(this.files).map(function(x) {
      return x.size || x.fileSize;
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);

    if (total > 10485759) {
      alert('Over Max Size');
      $('#submitBtn').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $('#submitBtn').prop("disabled", false);
    }


    $('#total').html('Total: ' + total + ' bytes');
  })
})
```

```css
#total {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" multiple="multiple" />
<button id="submitBtn">Submit Files</button>
<div id="total"></div>
```